# How to use aaa in radare2 while in -d (debug) mode?

Tags: debugging, radare2

This might be a stupid question, but I am trying to learn by myself and I encountered a problem which I cannot solve for the life of me. I tried googling and I can't find anything relevant, so here goes:

When I use the aaa command while not in debug mode, it works fine, but as soon as I go into debug mode and I go into the main function and type aaa, the following shows up:
[ ] Analyze all flags starting with sym. and entry0 (aa)

If I press enter nothing happens and I can just type freely without any effect.

How am I supposed to proceed?

Comment: are you on the latest version of r2? can you share the binary so we can check if we have the same experience?

Comment: Have same problem here. `radare2 3.4.0-git 21087 @ linux-x86-64 git.3.3.0-98-g1b89a8b4b
commit: 1b89a8b4b676b999d74a7d881335d20d61b6525a build: 2019-03-07__18:43:50` and here is the binary https://www.dropbox.com/s/7oagp3scl54btob/reverse_me?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

It's a known regression introduced in 3.3, workaround is:

```
e anal.bb.maxsize=1K
```

a proper fix will be in 3.4. This is the official answer: https://twitter.com/Kartone/status/1106318634220167168